# I can't type curly braces in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have been working with Java in an Eclipse IDE. I can type every single character just fine except for the '{' character. I need to resort to Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v every single time when I want to create a new block of {}.

In the Window>Preferences>Editor>Typing Braces are on, and they autocorrect just fine after I manage to copy a {.

Outside eclipse, in a text editor, or even in this question, I can type { by hitting Atl Gr + B, so I am thinking the problem is inside Eclipse.

Any help would be really appreciated, this error is getting quite annoying.

Comment: Do you not have a key for it?

Comment: Are  you trying Atl Gr + B in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I have a key for it, it is Alt gr + B and it works fine outside Eclipse.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem is with the skip breakpoints option.
After unbinding the Alt+B key command, try to unbind the Ctr+Alt+B (skip brakepoints).

This solved my problem.
If you try to type the "{" you can see the skip breakpoint option flashing.

Answer (score 14):

Go Windows-> Preferences type in search field 'binding' click on Keys, look up for Alt+B, click on it and then click Unbind Command.

Answer (score 1):

Because people work differently and on different things, Eclipse makes it easy to change shortcuts and also to view shortcuts for the commands you use a lot.

In your case:
Window->Preferences->Keys -> ctrl+alt+b Unbind Command should do the trick. It also the same in Spring Tool Suite 4(It is an Eclipse-based development environment.) 
There is a usefull article about eclipse commands: [How do you manage keyboard shortcuts](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2010/02/03/how-to-manage-keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse/)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Window → Perspective → Customize Perspective → Debug - → point on Skip All Breakpoints → Key bindings and change it form <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.